# jQuery traversing problem

Tags: jquery

I have a potentially infinitely nested tree of `ol > li`

given an li in the tree, i need to apply some function to all other `li`s below the given `li`, except within the current `ol`. As an example:

for example:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        Do not apply to me
        <ol>
            <li>Do not apply to me</li>
            <li>Do not apply to me</li>
        </ol> 
    </li>
    <li>
        Do not apply to me
        <ol>
            <li id='given'>I am the "given" li</li>  <------------- you are here
            <li>Do not apply to me</li>
            <li>
                Do not apply to me
                <ol>
                    <li>Do not apply to me</li>
                    <li>Do not apply to me</li>
                </ol> 
            </li>
        </ol> 
    </li>
    <li>
        Apply to me
    </li>
    <li>
        Apply to me
        <ol>
            <li>Apply to me</li>
            <li>
                Apply to me
                <ol>
                    <li>Apply to me</li>
                    <li>Apply to me</li>
                </ol> 
            </li>
        </ol> 
    </li>
</ol>
```

What's the most elegant way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: all LIs below the OL which is the parent of the given LI

Comment: You are missing a closing tag somewhere (I think an </li>) and I think that's why I don't understand the structure & pattern of the code snippet.

Comment: Please update the headline of this question - it gives almost no clue as to what the question is about.

Comment: @nicholaides fixed it, sorry about that! @asjo, to what? why don't you edit it if you think you can improve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
   $("#given").parents("li:first").nextAll("li").find("li").andSelf();
```

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon's answer will work with the given example, but if there is another OL immediately after the OL which contains #given, it won't work.

```
$("#given").parents("ol").nextAll("ol").find("li").each(function() {
    // function
});
$("#given").parents("li").nextAll("li").find("li").andSelf().each(function() {
    //function
});
```

This will work, but there's probably a more elegant way to accomplish it.